# HTML5 Audio recording getUserMedia with rezorder.js provide empty WAV file

Tags: html, wav, html5-audio

I'm recording audio with HTML5 getUserMedia function. My code is similar to example in https://github.com/rokgregoric/html5record/archive/master.zip, server receives correct Wav data. However all the data received are 0.

What the issue could be? I'm trying with Chrome 23.0.1271.95, my OS is Win7.

I've found similar issue described here: http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets# but it doesn't help in my case.

By the way examples based on record.js are not working for me too. The record went fine, but during playback there is only silence, same as for my server side record.

Comment: I've been using [recorder.js](https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js) with the exact same problem: recording works after I click Allow, it records but the audio is blank. Using Chrome Canary didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to be running Chrome Canary for getUserMedia. You'll also need to go to chrome://flags and make sure Web Audio Input is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Strange that it is not working in Chrome stable, it has the same Web Audio Input enabled flag.

Comment: Seems like this has been a long time coming.  How long before something makes it into stable Chrome after it is in Canary?  And then how long before it gets merged back into webkit?

Comment: I think the standard is about 11 weeks from Canary to stable - assuming things are working the way they want them to. As for when or if it gets merged back in to Webkit, I don't think there's any kind of definitive answer to that.